# Dual booting a Linux and Windows OS

Tags: linux, windows, multiboot

I'm aware of BerryBoot, but this only allows the multi-booting of two or more Linux based OSes, So is there anyway to boot two different OSes? If not, can you please explain why not, as well, please?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for NOOBS. As long as you're ok with Raspbian, or you're able to modify it to install another OS. NOOBS will allow you to install a few different OSs that are available if you have an internet connection and enough room on your sd card.

Windows 10 IoT is available (at least for the Pi2 and Pi3, haven't used NOOBS with my B+ in a long time) and can be installed alongside linux-based distros.

Comment: Windows 10 requires the 2 or 3.

Comment: Windows 7 itself takes hours to install on Pi2, so I'm not even going to try to install Win10. Is there any place where I can get Windows 3.0 or 95 to try out on my Pi2?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest getting NOOBS. You can get the Windows 10 IoT Preview OS, but you can't get the full Windows experience you'd expect to get. I'd suggest getting the OS 'Raspbian', as it is similar to Windows and is purely designed for the Pi. You could also Dual-Boot into the OS 'Kodi', a media-streaming OS that can act as an AirPlay device if set up correctly, which allows for streaming from Apple devices.